# Applying jQuery listeners to element's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button with a jQuery `contextmenu` listener.

In Safari and Chrome, when you right-click the button, the background goes blue for a second and then the text inside the button is selected/highlighted.

How can I prevent this?

```js
jQuery(".class1").contextmenu(function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="class1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I tested it in chrome and for me it doesn't do what you say. It works fine.

Comment: what is your chrome version and please share screenshot..created codepen and looks fine - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VjBYzW

Comment: Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit). I'm also on a Mac.

Comment: Perhaps add `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunatley not

Comment: I see the problem you're talking about ~ Chrome 51.0.2704.103 on OS X

Comment: `Click me` is not a children of a button ? it's not an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is selecting text inside the button then you can add `noselect` class to a button, you don't need to use js for that. But maybe I'm wrong.

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
/*maybe give it a static background .. */
button{
  background:yellow;
}
button:active{
  background:yellow!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="class1 noselect">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just found this for no selecting, but the problem persists of the button background color highlighting blue onclick.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you mentioned you're on a Mac, the blue background/border might be because you're using CTRL+LMB to click.

This will remove the focus on the button when CTRL is pressed:

```js
jQuery(".class1").contextmenu(function(e) {
    return false;
}).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17) { //CTRL
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="class1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't change the behavior unfortunately.